# Use string array as function parameters

Tags: c#, arrays, methods, parameters

I have done some research and I'm very surprise I did not find a solution for this simple problem.

---

**EDIT :** The question is about wether is that possible or does C# not provide any way to do what I'm trying to do

In the following example, I want to call `IWannaBeCalled` from `Linker` with the parameters from the `parameters` array. Basically the equivalent of calling

```
IWannaBeCalled(parameters[0], parameters[1]);
```

but the number of parameters must not be fixed : I wanna be able to add or remove parameters without changing the `Linker` method at all
Here is the sample code :

```
class Program
{
    private void IWannaBeCalled(string arg1, string arg2)
    {
        // Do stuffs using arg1 and arg2
    }

    private void Linker(params string[] parameters)
    {
        // ??
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Linker("Hello", "world");
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated ~

---

EDIT : Adding the real code in which I need to do that :

```
private PlanningDatas GetPlanningDatas(string dataSourceFunction, params string[] parameters)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(dataSourceFunction))
    {
        string methodName = dataSourceFunction.Split('.').Last();
        string classString = dataSourceFunction.Substring(0, dataSourceFunction.Length - methodName.Length - 1);

        Type targetType = Type.GetType(classString);
        MethodInfo targetMethod = targetType.GetMethod(methodName);

        return (PlanningDatas)targetMethod.Invoke(null, parameters);
    }
    else
    {
        //return (PlanningDatas)DefaultDataSource( --parameters-- );
    }
}

private PlanningDatas DefaultDataSource(string vehiculeModel)
{
    // Get the Data
}
```

Explanation : 
This example is from a mvc project so the method name is given through an **ajax call** so it have to be a string.
If a string is given, it calls the method but the dataSourceFunction is null it calls a default function.
All the uncommented code is fully functionnal

Comment: You *could* do that but you would need to use reflection. A better question would be why do you want to do this.... This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/386424). What is your end goal? Why are you trying to do this? Why not use the same signature as `Linker` ?

Comment: Use the `params` keyword, just like you are in with `Linker`.

Comment: @MattBurland If you mean calling `IWannaBeCalled(params parameters);` that does not work
@Igor I'm currently editing to add my real code

Comment: @Yanis.F: No, you change the signature of `IWannaBeCalled` to be `IWannaBeCalled(params string[] parameters)`

Comment: I could but I don't wanna have to do `string a = parameters[0]; string b = parameters[1]`

Comment: @Yanis.F using the `params` keyword is the correct answer to the question you are asking here. This is an XY problem.

Comment: Yea I just read what is an XY problem you are right it is one, my problem cannot be solved this way it seems to

Comment: I've edited to specify that the question is about wether it is possible rather than how to do it

Comment: Yeah, definitely an XY problem. I don't think you want to have an endpoint that will let an arbitrary function to be called on your backend. This seems like a Bad Idea™ from a security POV.